# python equation for finding turning point of derivative, while also using cost most efficiently

Tags: python, calculus

im attempting to make a program to optimise unit purchasing in a game, and i've hit a wall. so what i have so far, is i collect all the info price info of the 4 units (for example, unit 1 may cost 0.05, unit 2 may cost 1.01, unit 3 100.4, unit 4 30.3), the number of each unit you currently have (they can be sold/swapped) and the amount of money you have to spend, and use it to find the total money pool A.

now, assuming the unit types are A, B, C, D, the equation for your power is
power = (A + (B * 100)) * e^(log10((C * 5) * D))

is there a way of solving this equation for the highest power you can buy with your pool of money (you can buy fractional units, it does not need to be whole numbers)?

Comment: I can't understand your case. What do you mean with "1 is 0.05, 1 is 0.154, 1 is 100"? A understood a little less the second part. Could you, maybe, edit your question and add more detailed info?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on https://math.stackexchange.com/ it sounds to me like you're describing a problem which is much more complicated than it may initially appear. This looks like a multivariate optimization problem: you're trying to maximize `power` while minimizing a `cost` function. Fair warning, it's not a trivial task.

Comment: PS—I'm not really sure what you mean by "turning point of derivative", but it sounds a little like you're describing an inflection point, which is where the curvature of a function changes sign (from concave up to concave down or vice versa), and is located where the second derivative is zero.

Comment: @HélitonMartins i have edited that passage. does it make more sense now?

Comment: @blorgon fair enough, i figured this would be the right place to ask due to it being based in python. if it helps, im trying to maximise power by using all of the cost, not trying to minimise the cost

Comment: I'm suggesting you work out the math first, *then* look into implementing in Python. This is a math problem, not a Python problem, in other words.

Comment: @blorgon alright, ill do that. thanks!